# How do I delete my network profile after deleting all my accounts on all sites?

Tags: support, user-accounts, network-profile, deleted-accounts

If one has an account on any of the SE sites (Stack Overflow, Super User etc.), in order to delete their account, they can do so from their profile page. Numerous similar questions have been asked and answerers are always directed to this page:

[How do I delete my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account)

However, even after one has deleted all their accounts and one is not a participant of any of the communities, one continues to be logged in when they visit www.stackexchange.com. Now, if one clicks on any of the communities (Stack Overflow, Meta etc.), they are first asked to join. But how does one delete their master account, so that instead of being asked to join, they are first asked to log in?

Comment: It should be deleted automatically after some time.

Comment: In is case it seem to have took 40m, now deleted

Comment: @Nij That question does not cover how to delete stackexchange.com profiles (for which you cannot use the procedure there).

Comment: As a FAQ, it should, and needs to be updated otherwise. @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog

Comment: @Nij Until such update happens, this question should not be closed as a dupe. I don't know the answer after a long time searching for different posts.

Comment: @iDebug "Master account" is the wrong terminology. Please look at my edit.

Comment: @Sonic See my edit.

Comment: @Nij It's no covered there. The duplicate is invalid.

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't figured that out from the previous comment saying the exact same thing.

Comment: The FAQ [How can I delete my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account) has since been edited by an SE employee to explain the exact circumstances if and when a network profile will be deleted automatically after deleting all site accounts.

Answer (score 5):

The network profile we see in https://stackexchange.com is **not** the "master account". Actually, it's not an account at all.

This is only an overview of the site accounts, showing some interesting stats about them.

It can be deleted only by SE staff, so in order to have it deleted please click the "Contact" link in any site's footer, in the contact form choose "Other" and ask for it to be removed.